# Subquotient of principal series

Tags: rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms

Let $F$ be a local field of characteristic 0.

I am wondering whether an unramified principal series representation of $\operatorname{GL}_n(F)$ can have 1-dimensional quotient when $n>1$.

In some paper, the author claims that it can’t.

Do you know the reason?

Comment: This is true for the $\mathrm{GL}_2(F)$ principal series containing the special representation as a subrepresentation.

Comment: @Peter, How about unramified principal series representation of $GL_n(F)$ for $n>1$? Is this still don’t have 1-dimesional reps as a subquotient?

Comment: I just answered the case $n=2$. I don’t know the answer off the top of my head for $n>2$.

Comment: @Peter, Even in when n=2 case, unramified principal series representation of () can have 1-dimensional representation in some case? It’s so strange!

Comment: Look up the Steinberg representation

Comment: @PeterHumphries It's the same thing for general $n$---for the analogous induction of powers of absolute values from the Borel, one irreducible subquotient is Steinberg and one is trivial.  The trivial one is of course the unique unramified subquotient of the corresponding unramified reducible principal series.

Comment: @Kimball, Oh! Thank you very much! Every unramified principal series representation has at most 1-dimensional subquotient and that should the trivial representation. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Monty no, it's not necessarily trivial---you can also get unramified twists.

Comment: Why [automorphic-forms]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of $Ind_B^G 1$ as smooth functions on $G/B$ and look at the subspace of constant functions.

Comment: The constant function forms a 1-dimensional subrepresentation of $Ind_B^G 1$. But how about quotients? Does it can have 1-dimensional quotients?

Comment: Look at the contragriedient representation, it will be unramified principal series and ti will have trivial rep as a quotient.

Comment: @user152491, perhaps it would be worthwhile to enlarge your answer to include the point about taking contragredients...

Comment: @Monty, your question currently asks about subquotients, so it's probably best to edit it if you only want to discuss quotients.